# doGet() keeps appending data to the output instead of printing them in every request

Tags: java, servlets

I'm working on a servlet Java application, the problem is when I make a GET request to retrieve some data from the xml file, the browser keeps adding them instead of just showing them every request. For example, when I run the server and make a request the output looks like this:

```
Author::ID=0 Name=Terence Middle name=David John Last name=Prachett
Author::ID=1 Name=Jaros?aw Last name=Grz?dowicz
Author::ID=2 Name=J. Middle name=K. Last name=Rowling
Author::ID=3 Name=Andrzej Last name=Sapkowski
Author::ID=4 Name=Lorak Last name=A?ytjow
Author::ID=5 Name=Marcin Middle name=Jan Last name=Radziejewski

Go back
```

but when I refresh the page instead of printing the same data the browser prints:

```
Author::ID=0 Name=Terence Middle name=David John Last name=Prachett
Author::ID=1 Name=Jaros?aw Last name=Grz?dowicz
Author::ID=2 Name=J. Middle name=K. Last name=Rowling
Author::ID=3 Name=Andrzej Last name=Sapkowski
Author::ID=4 Name=Lorak Last name=A?ytjow
Author::ID=5 Name=Marcin Middle name=Jan Last name=Radziejewski
Author::ID=0 Name=Terence Middle name=David John Last name=Prachett
Author::ID=1 Name=Jaros?aw Last name=Grz?dowicz
Author::ID=2 Name=J. Middle name=K. Last name=Rowling
Author::ID=3 Name=Andrzej Last name=Sapkowski
Author::ID=4 Name=Lorak Last name=A?ytjow
Author::ID=5 Name=Marcin Middle name=Jan Last name=Radziejewski

Go back
```

And it keeps adding those data every request.

Here's the code for the GET request in the servlet:

```
@Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        library.Authors authors = new library.Authors();
        if(storageEngine.equals("xml")){
            try {
                saxParser.parse(new File(xmlFile), ah);
                authors = ah.getAuthors();
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if(storageEngine.equals("sql")){
            try {
                library.LibrarySQLDAO sqldao = new library.LibrarySQLDAO(sqliteFile);
                authors = sqldao.getAuthors();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        List<Authors.Author> au = authors.getAuthors();

        for (Authors.Author author: au) if (author != null) out.write(author + "</br>");
        out.write("<br/><a href=\"/LibraryWeb/authors.jsp\">Go back</a>");
    }
```

I'm relatively new to Java, especially servlets. I tried to find the answer in the web, but I didn't find any valuable information. Please give me a hint what could I do wrong.

EDIT:
Here's the code to the library.Authors class:

```
package library;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class Authors{
    
    public static class Author extends Person {
        private String id;

        public Author(String id, String firstName, String middleName, String lastName) {
            super(firstName, middleName, lastName);
            this.id = id;
        }
        
        public String getId() {
            return this.id;
        }
        
        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            if (this.middleName != null) {
                return "Author::ID=" + this.id + " Name=" + this.firstName + " Middle name=" + this.middleName + " Last name=" + this.lastName;
            }
            return "Author::ID=" + this.id + " Name=" + this.firstName + " Last name=" + this.lastName;
        } 
        
    }
    
    private List<Author> authors = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public Author getAuthor(String id){
        
        ListIterator<Author> litr = authors.listIterator();
        for(int i = 0; i < authors.size(); i++) {
            while (litr.hasNext()) {
                Author element = litr.next();
                if (element.getId().equals(id)) {
                    return element;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public int getAuthorsNumber() {
        return authors.size();
    }
    
    public List<Author> getAuthors(){
        return this.authors;
    }
    
    public void addAuthor(Author author) {
        authors.add(author);
    }
    
}
```

EDIT2:
This happens on EVERY request to this servlet, when I do POST request, same thing happens, those authors keep appending.

The AuthorHandler class:

```
package library.SAXHandlers;

import library.Authors;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class AuthorHandler extends DefaultHandler implements Author {

    private final Authors authorsList = new Authors();
    private StringBuilder data = null;

    boolean bFirstName = false;
    boolean bMiddleName = false;
    boolean bLastName = false;
    String id = null;

    private Authors.Author author = new Authors.Author(null, null, null, null);

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) {
        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("au:Author")){
            id = attributes.getValue("id");
            author.setId(id);
        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("ps:FirstName") && id!=null) {
            bFirstName = true;
        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("ps:MiddleName") && id!=null) {
            bMiddleName = true;
        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("ps:LastName") && id!=null) {
            bLastName = true;
            id = null;
        }
        data = new StringBuilder();
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) {

        if(bFirstName) {
            author.setFirstName(data.toString());
            bFirstName = false;
        } else if(bMiddleName) {
            author.setMiddleName(data.toString());
            bMiddleName = false;
        } else if(bLastName) {
            author.setLastName(data.toString());
            bLastName = false;
        }
        if (author.getLastName()!=null){
            authorsList.addAuthor(author);
            author = new Authors.Author(null, null, null, null);
            id = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {
        data.append(new String(ch, start, length));
    }

    @Override
    public Authors.Author getAuthor(String id) {
        return authorsList.getAuthor(id);
    }

    @Override
    public Authors getAuthors(){
        return authorsList;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show the code that is invoking and printing? Also, if you call the same code via Postman or curl do you get the same result? It does not seams to be a problem in this code that you are displaying.

Comment: It could be that this:               saxParser.parse(new File(xmlFile), ah); 
makes you append to the same file and therefore it's saved?

Comment: @GamingFelix it doesn't append to any file, I use the SAX parser only to read data, for writing i use something else.

Comment: @pringi I've never used Postman, but when I use curl I get the same result.

Comment: @pringi what code do you want me to show? I don't understand.

Comment: As my pre-commentors, I can't find an error in the code you have posted... It is very unclean and clunky code, but it should work just fine. So, the issue has to be in the getAuthors method or maybe in your library.Authors class. 
This is a great example why Test-Driven-Developement is a good practice. Try adding tests for all self written classes. Eg. test what your custom AuthorHandler is doing, test what the parser is producing, and test what actually is in your library.Authors object... 

And where you are at it, perhaps clean up the whole mess a bit. ^^

Comment: @3Fish I'll do it, thanks. Sorry for my incompetence.

Comment: Could you share the code for the `library.Authors` class?

Comment: @ThomasKläger it's added.

Comment: @Hellmick, no problem... we all were once at that point :)

Please also add the Handler class and the parser(if it is a custom parser)

Comment: @3Fish it is, I've added it.

Answer (score 1):

OK,

I have found only one potential issue source.
It seems to me that the AuthorHandler "ah" is reused every time. And the internal Authors List of the handler is never cleared. That means that the Authorhandler already contains a list with all authors previously loaded from the file.

I guess you should either make your handler stateless (eg. no internal list of authors) or at least clear it every time, after you are done.

Comment: Or (IMHO the best solution) create a new AuthorHandler for each request

Comment: Thanks! I can't make the handler stateless unless I'll rebuild the full project. What do you mean to clear the handler? I found only SAXParser.reset() method, but it doesn't seem to work with that. I can't find any method to clear the handler in oracle docs.

Comment: @ThomasKläger I've done it the way you told me and it worked! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Hellmick you can just clear the authorsList either with an extra function you add to your handler or just clear it at the end of the getAuthors call... but recreating the handler works just as well